# Alternatives to the baked-in ASP.NET authentication model

Tags: php, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

When I look at how devs implement login and "authentication" in other web frameworks it looks like they most of the time they just set a server session and check if that's set or not, before they let people in. We even did this in ASP classic back in the day and it seemed to work just fine.

e.g
RoR: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575551/User-Authentication-in-Ruby-on-Rails
Php: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Implementing a custom membership provider can seem as a long way to go for logging in users, and say Session.Abandon when they're done. And frankly I am not sure I do understand the security risks in not using the Membership provider, even though I have for many years.

A few thoughts please.

Comment: How do you plan on securing static content? Session variables can work for controlling who has access to your Classic ASP webpages but they don't prevent clients from accessing non-ASP content.

Comment: I am not refering to content, I am refering to authentication. Nothing to do with ASP classic. It has to do with not wanting to use Forms Authentication any longer :)

Comment: Right, I understand. I'm just curious how you plan on securing your website content without using a membership provider, like ASP.NET Forms Authentication. Session variables don't prevent people from hotlinking directly to your static content.

Comment: @Bond Forms Authentication doesn't protect static content from being browsed either. Whether you choose Forms Authentication or Session variables, you still need to move static content to a location that cannot be browsed (App_Data, outside of the root) and then use a handler to serve it. You perform your authentication in the ProcessRequest method of the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms Authentication is not dependent on Membership Providers. You can use Forms Authentication on its own, which is what I have done in the past. Here's an article that describes how: [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

There is nothing to stop you using a Session variable to track users instead. There are no security implications in doing this either, so long as you follow basic secure coding principals:

1. Never trust user input
2. Always use parameters/stored procedures in your data access
3. Encrypt/hash any passwords that you store.